# Running time and stack depth of a lisp recurrence

Tags: algorithm-analysis, programming-languages, recurrence-relation

Consider the following sequence $a_n$:

\begin{align*}
  a_0 &= \alpha \\
  a_k &= \beta a_{k-1} + \kappa
\end{align*}

Now consider the implementation of this sequence via lisp:

```
(defun an (k)
  (if (= k 0) alpha
    (+ (* beta (an (- k 1))) kappa)))
```

What is the running time to compute `(an k)` just as it is written? Also, what would be the maximum stack depth reached? My hypothesis would be that both the running time and stack depth are $O(k)$ because it takes $k$ recursive calls to get to the base case and there is one call per step and one stack push per step.\
.

Is this analysis corect?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct.

Comment: Emacs lisp is telling me it is running out of stack space to compute $a_8$... So I was just making sure I am not going crazy! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time and other resources (such as stack consumption) needed to run `an` with the argument $x \in \mathbb{N}^*$ is the sum of:

- the resources needed to compute `(- k 1)` with `k` bound to $x$;
- the resources needed to compute `an` with the argument $x-1$;
- the resources needed to compute `(if (= k 0) alpha (+ (* beta` $y$`) kappa))` where $y$ is the value returned by the recursive call to `an`.

Let $T(x)$ be the running time of this computation. For $x \gt 0$, by the analysis above, $T(x) = T(x-1) + C$ for some constant $C$ (assuming that the arithmetic operations take constant time). A very simple induction shows that $T(x) = C \, x + T(0)$, i.e. $T(x) = \Theta(x)$. The same goes for stack consumption.

There is more than one stack push per recursive call, (3 in a naive interpreted Lisp such as Emacs Lisp), but that doesn't affect the $O$ or $\Theta$ analysis. Other than this minor detail your analysis is correct.

Are you sure that you typed the right code? Emacs has a fairly low limit on stack usage but even it can sustain more recursive calls (up to 123 in Emacs 23 where `max-lisp-eval-depth` is 500).